# FFMPEG h264 grey frame and artifacts at beginning

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm splitting my "zi6 quicktime mov" hd videos, I have 250 clips of around 10 or 15 seconds each, from lot of places, locationes around the globe and want to combine them in a single big clip.

I can merge them very good with "mkvmerge".

The problem is that the first frames of all videos in the collection (splitted with ffmpeg), are gray or with artifacts at beggining, I do not know how to explain, maybe wrong ffmpeg commands, I'm doing this (with batch command line, which is great / fast for me):

=======begin of batch file

```
ffmpeg -i jockey_club_fpv.mov -ss 00:00:17 -t 00:00:24 -g 1 -sameq -vcodec copy -vf fade=in:0:30 partes3a.mov
ffmpeg -i jockey_club_fpv.mov -ss 00:04:40 -t 00:00:20 -g 1 -sameq -vcodec copy -vf fade=in:0:30 partes3b.mov
ffmpeg -i jockey_club_fpv.mov -ss 00:05:35 -t 00:01:00 -g 1 -sameq -vcodec copy -vf fade=in:0:30 partes3c.mov
ffmpeg -i jockey_club_fpv.mov -ss 00:07:11 -t 00:00:10 -g 1 -sameq -vcodec copy -vf fade=in:0:30 partes3d.mov
ffmpeg -i jockey_club_fpv.mov -ss 00:07:45 -t 00:00:21 -g 1 -sameq -vcodec copy -vf fade=in:0:30 partes3e.mov
ffmpeg -i jockey_club_fpv.mov -ss 00:08:47 -t 00:00:05 -g 1 -sameq -vcodec copy -vf fade=in:0:30 partes3f.mov
ffmpeg -i jockey_club_fpv.mov -ss 00:09:18 -t 00:00:10 -g 1 -sameq -vcodec copy -vf fade=in:0:30 partes3g.mov
ffmpeg -i jockey_club_fpv.mov -ss 00:09:35 -t 00:00:09 -g 1 -sameq -vcodec copy -vf fade=in:0:30 partes3h.mov
ffmpeg -i jockey_club_fpv.mov -ss 00:10:07 -t 00:00:16 -g 1 -sameq -vcodec copy -vf fade=in:0:30 partes3i.mov
mkvmerge -o join4.mov partes3a.mov + partes3b.mov + partes3c.mov + partes3d.mov + partes3e.mov + partes3f.mov + partes3g.mov + partes3h.mov + partes3i.mov
```

=======end of batch file

Thanks a lot for any answer!!

Comment: Just a quick question: Do you see the same artifacts if you remove the fade filter?